# bootstrap2 table fixed instead of responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap wrap and an trying to build a registration page that looks somewhat decent. I thought I had it styled correctly, but then when I rescaled the page I resized that the table is not responsive.

I know that in bootstrap3 they added table responsiveness, but I cannot use that with this specific wrap. Are there any tricks in bootstrap2 to help fix this?

Here is a jsFiddle I'm working with http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6817/

I have tried a few things such as adding `span` classes, but that didn't seem to help at all...it just seemed to clutter it instead.

Comment: The project I'm currently working on used Bootstrap in a first design iteration, and my attempts to make fluid tables always had one or multiple defects.

Comment: @Stijn at least you were able to make it fluid. I cant seem to make it happen at all.

Answer (score 1):

You defeating the point of Bootstrap by using a table for a layout. Bootstrap already ships with classes to columns. Use those.

You can read more on this here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

To create such a layout, you can do the following. Responsive is no longer an issue. You can now decide if you want to use `.row` or `.row-fluid` assuming you are using Bootstrap 2.x.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">Col 1</div>
  <div class="span4">Col 2</div>
  <div class="span4">Col 3</div>
</div>
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zH8gb/1/ - Make sure the viewport is wide enough to see the feect. Drag the Result area window to enlarge it.

Comment: I was using those, but they do not work in particular situation. They didn't style like I need them to. If I could get around the table I would, trust me...I hate tables

Comment: I'm pretty sure using the BS layout should have no bearing on your styles. Something is wrong with your CSS, probably.

Comment: I don't have anything in my css except for that form and I only added that after I had the table in there.

Comment: When you say you can't get the style you need, what do you mean? There's nothing in the layout that should interfere with your styling. The layout just gives you columns. How you style your elements is independent, unless you are adding padding/margins to the column divs, which breaks the column layout.

Comment: I was talking about how the input interacts with the label. I currently have a float on each and then clearing it. When I do so in just the row and spans then they do not line up correctly

Comment: I've used BS to make this layout a bunch of times. Do you have a fiddle? It doesn't sound right.

Comment: also three span4's do not line up horizontally, one wraps around to the bottom even in full screen

Comment: First of all, you're not importing the CSS file properly. Second of all, you still haven't structured your HTML properly. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/zH8gb/1/ - Make sure you drag the window handle so that it's big enough to show everything line up.

Comment: Sorry, that was just an import I googoled and then copied and pasted. My html may not have lined up correctly, but it was valid and that was how I was getting it in my window locally. My issue is with floating the label beside the input, when you do so it pushes the third input below the others and that is just not acceptable.

Comment: This still does not work for my situation. One the labels will not float next to the inputs, and two even at full width the last input drops below the rest of the inputs. My viewport it fine, everything else works fine, except for this form. Which is why I was trying to make the table responsive because I could get that to format properly unlike this.